# Continuous Sync between Outlook 2007 Calendar and Google Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar, google-calendar

I have a user that wants to sync their Outlook 2007 calendar with Google Calendar so they can get their schedule on their phone. Now, I've seen how to set this up to transfer calendar to calendar but I want a continuous sync.... is this possible and if so, can someone please help me out with instructions to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As this tweet* has revived this post, I'll post an answer. A third party tool like http://phw198.github.io/OutlookGoogleCalendarSync will be able to do this for you - it can either be installed or the portable version unzipped to a folder on your computer, so no administrator privileges are required.

The tool will step you through authentication with your Google calendar and is very straight forward to configure with an automated sync schedule, or even when something changes on your Outlook calendar.

Also it's completely free and open source! (For full disclosure, I'm its developer).

- https://twitter.com/super_user/status/1303392668978999298